# flutter How to put data from multiple json api urls into once?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to put data from multiple json api urls into once?

I have multiple databases endpoints. The first is storing a code, like status: 2
The second database is storing information:

state_name: Okay

state_id: 2

So my question is, how to get the state_name from first json http request.
I want to print the state_name in an ListTile.

Thanks for your help.
If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: I think this question needs code snippet. There's many way to achieve this and it doesn't mention using what endpoints. And it's hard to see an effort of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving the data with a Stream? If yes, you can use the condition "where"

```
   snapshot.data.where((element) => element.state_name == "Okay" ),
```